# Extension point for set website ids product in case admin not set website

Tags: magento2, product, plugin, multi-website

This is my scenario I have hidden `website_ids` field in product form (default magento show it)
So how i can use plugin for set website ids for product when it create. Is there any entry-point to do this

My goal is if not website ids available when post data so init default website ids for product

Added modifier for modify Form:

```
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    $this->_meta = unset($meta['websites']);
    return $this->_meta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I post my answer here in case someone in future may need

Create **di.xml** file for prepare plugin class

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper">
    <plugin name="updateProductWebsiteIds" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Controller\Product\Initialization\Helper\WebsitePlugin" sortOrder="40" />
</type>
```

original class [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper.php)

Add new file Class **WebsitePlugin**

```
public function afterInitialize(
    \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper $subject,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
) {
    if (Add your logic check here  && isset($product)) {
        if (!$product->getWebsiteIds()) {
            $defaultWebsiteId = $this->storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getWebsiteId();
            $websitesIds = [$defaultWebsiteId];
            $product->setWebsiteIds($websitesIds);
        }
    }
    return $product;
}
```